# Why did Sergeant Han ask that question?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, skyscraper

In *[Skyscraper (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyscraper_(2018_film))*, Sergeant Han describes Will Sawyer’s wife Sarah to Inspector Wu:

> Sergeant Han: His wife was a navy surgeon. She did three tours in Afghanistan. **The family's been residing in the building**.

Later in the movie, Sergeant Han & Inspector Wu watched Will Sawyer gets into skyscraper in a very risky way:

> Sergeant Han: **What would drive a man to head into those flames?**
>
> Officer: Sir... We're able to locate Will Sawyer's family.
>
> Inspector Wu: Tell me something I don't know. They're in that building.

If she knows that Will Sawyer's family present in that building, then why did
she ask that question?

Comment: She doesn't know? "The family's been residing in the building." says nothing about the family's current location, and therefore doesn't indicate knowledge that they're currently inside the building. I'm currently at work in an office, but I haven't stopped living (residing) in my apartment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the lines represent the juxtaposition of character. The entire movie is about how honorable, selfless, and heroic Sawyer is. One way to drive this home is to have 'outside normal people' question the heroic actions he takes. It's 'utterly unthinkable' to these 'normal people' that someone would face certain death for their loved one. That makes what Sawyer does MORE heroic. He's not the average man. He does things normal people wouldn't. I think that's what they're going for anyway.